# Poly vs. Inheritance

Tags: inheritance, polymorphism

When is it wise to use polymorphism over Inheritance?

So, let's say we have

```
public class Lion extends Animals {} ;
```

OR

```
Animals ani = new Lion();
```

I would mostly prefer inheritance, since we have solid class to use.

Does it come down to which one runs faster?

Comment: It's not clear what are you contradicting here. Also in general polymorphism is achieved via inheritance.

Comment: In *Java*, one can't use Polymorphism without Inheritance *or* Interfaces. The above example with `extends` shows Inheritance and the assignment shows [*type widening*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html), but Interfaces would work just as well. (Some people argue that Composition should be used over Inheritance and others argue that Interfaces should always be used with Inheritance.)

Comment: (I guess one could technically argue that reflection also enables Polymorphism, but I'm not going to recognize that as a sane approach. Also Polymorphism can be *simulated* - e.g. like C type-switch dispatches - but this is also outside of language-level support.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Or to that.

```
public class Lion extends Animals {} ;
```

defines a class Lion, that descends from a class animal

```
Animals ani = new Lion();
```

defines an variable ani of type Animals and assigns a new instance of Lion to it.

If Lion didn't descend from Animals, then you'd get a error, is about all we can say.